# Why more polygons produces a more detailed end result on the material

Tags: textures, polygon, resolution, cinema-4d

I have a C4D material made with a couple of layers (diffuse, bump, displacement, reflectance), on each layer there is 4K image, so there is alot of details on them. If I apply that material to a cube or a sphere, as I increase the number of polygons, the level of detail also increases, instead if there are just a few poligons, the result looks bad.

I want to know how everything works under the hood (maybe is not such a big deal). I guess what the render engine is doing is taking that image and applying it on the number of poligons, but why applying the whole image in 1 polygon is not the same than subdividing the image and then applying smaller pieces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those maps (Bump, displacement, etc) allow the engine to manipulate polygons normals... If you don't have enough polygons, it's like giving 4K different value to the same polygon. so nothing will change in the objects structure, it will not get deformed, which means no bumps no shadows and no displacement.
If this helps, please consider up-voting and marking your question as answered !